# Round robin assignment of tasks - AppScript solution?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, round-robin

I have a form response sheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YCneMRUC6ZKK0V3qs0mROhr6j62mdNIWAxcW71aAQIg/edit#gid=0) which saves all the requests from our stakeholders, and our workflow lead has to manually assign these requests to the members of our team in a round-robin fashion while ensuring each of the team members has an equal distribution of requests.

However, if a duplicate task is submitted (which is very much possible), it should be assigned to the same person that handled it earlier.

Is it possible to employ Google scripts solution to get this type of random yet equal distribution of tasks among the assignee group? The agent availability on any given day is also important, as they could be out of office, therefore the workflow lead keeps revising the agent list almost on a daily basis. Hence, it's all the more useful to have a Google AppScript solution to this problem (assigning one task at a time to the next available agent in queue). If the script can email the agent that would be ideal, but not necessary. Kindly advise! Thanks.

Comment: This looks like more as a requirement rather than a programming question. Have you tried to write the code to implement it?

Comment: It sounds like it’s possible to do with Google Apps Script. The real question is it possible for you to do?

Comment: Nope, am afraid I'm not that familiar with AppsScript to do this. Would really appreciate any help/guidance here. Thanks!

Comment: What triggers the assignment?

Comment: Why are there two columns of  different **desired assignment** columns?

Comment: When and how are assignments removed?

Answer (score 1):

## Round Robin Assignment

This script provides the following assignments:

1. If task title is repeated it assigns that task to original assignee.
2. If task title is new then it assigns that task to the assignee that has the least tasks.
3. If the title is new and all assignees have the same number of tasks then it makes a random selection with `Math.floor(Math.random() * assigneeArray.length);`

Here's the code:

Code.gs:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
  .addItem('Add Task', 'addTask')
  .addItem('Add Assignee', 'addAssignee')
  .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Utility')
  .addItem('Select Columns Skip Header', 'jjeSUS1.selectColumnsSkipHeader')
  .addItem('Create Named Range', 'jjeSUS1.createNamedRange'))
  .addToUi();
}
function addAssignee() {
  showFormDialog({filename:'addAssignee',title:'Add Assignee'});
}

function postAssigneeData() {
}

function addTask() {
  showFormDialog({filename:'addTask',title:'Add Task'}); 
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function showFormDialog(dObj){
  var form=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(dObj.filename).getContent();
  var ui=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('html').evaluate();
  ui.append(form);
  ui.append("</body></html>");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, dObj.title);
}

function saveData(dObj) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(dObj.sheetName);
  var hrg=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var hA=hrg.getValues()[0];
  var vA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<hA.length;i++) {
    vA.push((dObj[hA[i]])?dObj[hA[i]]:'');//Column headers must agree with form names
  }
  dObj['row']=sh.getLastRow()+1;
  var cA=Object.keys(dObj).filter(function(el){return (el!=='row' && el !='sheetName')});
  for(var i=0;i<cA.length;i++) {
    saveValue(dObj.row,cA[i],dObj[cA[i]],dObj.sheetName,1);
  }
  return dObj;
}

function makeAssignment(aObj) {
  Logger.log(aObj);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Assignments')
  var title=aObj.Title;
  var taskObj=getTasks();
  //Check to see if someone has already done this once
  if(taskObj.taskA.indexOf(title)>-1) {
    saveValue(aObj.row,'Assignment',taskObj[aObj.Title],'Assignments',1);
    saveValue(aObj.row,'Date',Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MM d, yyyy HH:mm"),'Assignments',1);
    postTaskData(aObj.Title,taskObj[aObj.Title]);
  }else{
    var assA=getAssigneeTasks();
    if(assA[0].allCountsEqual=='false') {
      //they don't have the same number of tasks so take the lowest one
      saveValue(aObj.row,'Assignment',assA[0].email,'Assignments',1);
      saveValue(aObj.row,'Date',Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MM d, yyyy HH:mm"),'Assignments',1);   
      postTaskData(aObj.Title,assA[0].email);
    }else{
      //they all have the same number of task so take a random one
      var n=Math.floor(Math.random()*assA.length);
      saveValue(aObj.row,'Assignment',assA[n].email,'Assignments',1);
      saveValue(aObj.row,'Date',Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MM d, yyyy HH:mm"),'Assignments',1);
      postTaskData(aObj.Title,assA[n].email);
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function getTasks() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var taskObj={'taskA':[]};
  var h=jjeSUS1.getColumnHeight(1, sh, ss);
  if(h>2) {
    var rg=sh.getRange(3,1,h-2,2);  
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
      taskObj[vA[i][0]]=vA[i][1];
      if(taskObj.taskA.indexOf(vA[i][0])==-1) {
        taskObj.taskA.push(vA[i][0]);//Unique Task Array
      }    
    }
  }
  return taskObj
}

function postTaskData(key,value) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  sh.appendRow([key,value]);

}

function getAssigneeTasks() {
  var taskObj=getTasks();
  var aeqA=getAssignees().map(function(el){return {email:el,count:0,allCountsEqual:'false'}});
  var keysA=Object.keys(taskObj).filter(function(el){return (el != 'taskA')});
  for(var i=0;i<aeqA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<keysA.length;j++) {
      if(taskObj[keysA[j]]==aeqA[i].email){
        aeqA[i].count+=1;
      }
    }
  }
  aeqA.sort(function(a,b){return a.count - b.count;});
  var isTrue=true;
  var maxCount=aeqA[aeqA.length-1].count;
  aeqA.forEach(function(el){if(el.count!=maxCount){isTrue=false;}});
  if(isTrue) {
    aeqA.map(function(el){return el.allCountsEqual='true';});
  }
  return aeqA;
}

function saveValue(row,columnName,value,sheetName,headerRow) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var hA=sh.getRange(headerRow,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  sh.getRange(row,hA.indexOf(columnName)+1).setValue(value);
}

function getAssignees() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Assignees');
  var hrg=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var hA=hrg.getValues()[0];
  return sh.getRange(2, hA.indexOf('Email')+1, sh.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0]});
}

function closeDialog() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dummy');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface,'Closing');
}
```

css.html:

```
<style>
body {background-color:#ffffff;}
input[type="button"],input[type="text"]{margin:0 0 2px 0;}
</style>
```

resources.html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

html.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('resources') ?>
    <?!= include('css') ?>
    <?!= include('script') ?>
  </head>
  <body>
```

script.html:

```
<script>    
     $(function(){  
       document.getElementById('txt1').focus();

      });
    function getInputObject(obj) {
      var rObj={};
      var length=Object.keys(obj).length;
      for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
        console.log('Name: %s Type: %s',obj[i].name,obj[i].type);
        if(obj[i].type=="text"){
          rObj[obj[i].name]=obj[i].value;
        }
        if(obj[i].type=="select-one"){
          rObj[obj[i].name]=obj[i].options[obj[i].selectedIndex].value;
        }
        if(obj[i].type="hidden"){
          if(obj[i].name) {
            rObj[obj[i].name]=obj[i].value;
          }
        }
      }
      return rObj;
    }

    function processForm(obj){
      var fObj=getInputObject(obj);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(fObj));
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(rObj){
        document.getElementById("btn").disabled=true;
        $('#msg').html('<br /><h1>Data Saved.</h1>');
        if(rObj.sheetName=='Assignments') {
          google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(function(){
            $('#msg').html('<br /><h1>Assignments Complete.</h1>');
            google.script.host.close();
          })
          .makeAssignment(rObj);
          }else{
            google.script.host.close();
          }
        })
        .saveData(fObj);
      }
     console.log('My Code');
</script>
```

addAssignee.html:

```
<div id="heading"><h1>Add Assignee</h1></div>
<div id="content">
<h3>Please Enter First Name, Last Name, Phone and Email into the text areas adjacent to the text box labels.</h3>
    <form id="assigneeForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();processForm(this);" >
      <br /><input type="text" id="txt1" name="First" /> First
      <br /><input type="text" id="txt2" name="Last" /> Last
      <br /><input type="text" id="txt3" name="Phone" /> Phone
      <br /><input type="text" id="txt3" name="Email" /> Email
      <br /><input type="hidden" value="Assignees" name="sheetName" />
      <br /><input id="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
      <br />
    </form>
</div>
<div id="msg"></div>
<div id="cntl"><input type="button" id="btn" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" ></div>
```

addTask.html:

```
<div id="heading"><h1>Add Task</h1></div>
<div id="content">
<h3>Please Enter Title and Description into the text areas adjacent to the text box labels.</h3>
    <form id="assigneeForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();processForm(this);" >
      <br /><input type="text" id="txt1" name="Title" /> Title
      <br /><input type="text" id="txt2" name="Description" /> Description
      <br /><input type="hidden" value="Assignments" name="sheetName" />
      <br /><input id="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
      <br />
    </form>
</div>
<div id="msg"></div>
<div id="cntl"><input type="button" id="btn" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" ></div>
```

The three pages of my spreadsheet look as follows: (names are on images)

[image]

[image]

[image]

1. [JavaScript Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
2. [JavaScript Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)
3. [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service)
4. [Templated Html](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)
5. [Public Libraries](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VrT_2hKGiDwvWql4g285ghuNO06pkBRmeTNNRqtOifY/edit#gid=0)